# How come WMS can serve KML? Isn't WMS only meant to serve images?

Tags: geoserver, wms, kml

If you go to GeoServer, layer preview, by clicking "KML" in the "Common formats" column you get a KML file that contains a URL that can be used to get all information for a layer. For example:

https://chemicalse.etme.gr/geoserver/etme/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&layers=etme:LAKES&styles=Lake&height=2048&width=2048&transparent=false&srs=EPSG:4326&format_options=AUTOFIT:true;KMATTR:true;KMPLACEMARK:false;KMSCORE:40;MODE:refresh;SUPEROVERLAY:false&BBOX=20.80842303827691,37.61065467534937,24.69512143309823,39.82801902683197

This is a WMS request (it contains `service=WMS`). I thought WMS requests only download images, but this request downloads the full data for the layer, including the coordinates of the lines (essentially the layer in vector format). I thought you'd need to use WFS for that.

The thing is that I want to permit a user to view the image of a layer (on a Leaflet map), but I don't want users to be able to download the data for the layer. I deactivated WFS for unauthorized users, but that isn't enough if they can get a KML with WMS.

What have I understood wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Basically, a WMS can server anything it wants provided it lists them in the getCapabilities document

Comment: Pay attention to GetFeatureRequest as well. It can also use some vector format as INFO_FORMAT and even text/plain returns the attribute data. Consider what you want to publish and what to hide.

Comment: Thanks a lot people!

Comment: KML isn't a vector only format, you can serve images too.  WMS can be used for vector tiles, and videos, not just images though that is it's commonest form.  WMS gives a  generalised view of one or more sets of data, not the actual data.